# "keine Zähne putzen" oder "die Zähne nicht putzen"?

Tags: word-order, negation, adverbial

Wie ich verstanden habe, es gibt einige Verben/Konstruktionen, die immer ein Objekt oder eine adverbiale Bestimmung brauchen. Ich habe mich daran gewöhnt, diese Objekte/Bestimmungen als trennbare Präfixe zu behandeln. Also stelle ich sie an das Ende des Satzes, und „nicht“ kommt vor diese Wörter.

- **Ich gehe in die Schule.**
  Die Gruppe „in die Schule“ ist eine gebundene adverbiale Bestimmung, also stehen diese Worte am Ende des Satzes.
- **Ich gehe jeden Tag schon seit 3 Jahren mit meiner Schwester in die Schule.**
  Die Bestimmung steht immer noch am Ende des Satzes.
- **Ich gehe heute nicht in die Schule.**
  Das Wort „nicht“ kommt vor die Bestimmung.

Ich dachte, mit gebundenen Akkusativ-Objekten ist es auch so: Stelle sie an das Ende des Satzes und schreibe die Verneiung „nicht“ (oder „kein“) davor. Aber ich habe kurz im Internet nachgesehen, und es scheint mehrere Varianten zu geben:

1. Mein Kind will sich heute **die Zähne nicht putzen.**
2. Mein Kind will sich heute **keine Zähne putzen.**

Welche ist richtig und warum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt noch eine dritte Version, die vermutlich sogar die am häufigsten verwendete ist:

> Mein Kind will sich heute **nicht die Zähne putzen.**

In dieser Version bildet *»die Zähne putzen«* eine semantische Einheit, die einen bestimmten Vorgang beschreibt, und die Verneinung steht vor dieser Gruppe, um die Gruppe als Ganzes zu negieren. Die Weigerung des Kindes bezieht sich also nicht auf das Putzen an sich, oder darauf, irgend etwas mit den Zähnen zu machen, sondern ganz konkret auf die Kombination aus beidem: Das Putzen der Zähne wird abgelehnt.

Die beiden anderen Versionen bedeuten zwar im Grunde dasselbe, und es muss betont werden, dass auch sie völlig korrekte deutsche Sätze sind, aber sie weisen feine, kaum wahrnehmbare Nuancen in der Bedeutung auf, die auch der Grund dafür sind, warum man sie seltener verwendet:

> Mein Kind will sich heute die Zähne nicht putzen.

Hier steht die Verneinung nur vor dem Verb *putzen.* Es geht also nicht um die Zahnpflege, sondern es wird (zumindest auf den ersten Blick) eine allgemeine Abneigung gegen jegliches Putzen formuliert, die sich - mehr oder weniger zufällig - in Akt des Zähneputzens manifestiert. Wie gesagt ist das eine sehr feine Färbung der Bedeutung, die sowohl vom Sprecher als auch vom Hörer meist gar nicht bewusst wahrgenommen wird und in Wahrheit auch unbedeutend ist. Aber sie führt dazu, dass sich dieser Satz *ein wenig seltsam* anfühlt und daher nicht so häufig verwendet wird wie der erste.

> Mein Kind will sich heute keine Zähne putzen.

Das Indefinitpronomen *»kein«* hat sich aus althochdeutsch *»nih ein«* (übersetzt in modernes Deutsch: *»nicht ein«*) im Mittelhochdeutschen über *»nech ein«* und *»neck ein«,* dann *»nek-ein«* und *»ne-kein«* weiter zu *»kein«* verändert. Und auch heute noch wird *»kein«* als Synonym für *»nicht ein«* verstanden.

Wenn das Kind also *»keine Zähne«* putzen will, dann will es vordergründig zwar etwas putzen, aber das, was es putzen möchte, ist *»nicht ein Zahn«,* also keinen einzigen Zahn. Streng genommen sagt dieser Satz also aus, dass das Kind zwar gerne etwas putzen möchte (denn das Verb *putzen* ist nicht verneint), aber es will auf keinen Fall Zähne putzen (sondern vielleicht irgend etwas anderes, was aber nicht Teil der Aussage des Satzes ist).

Beachte, dass auch diese Interpretation im Grund darauf hinausläuft, dass das Kind die Zahnpflege ablehnt. Die beschriebene Bedeutung ist also auch in diesem Satz nur eine kleine Abwandlung der Weigerung des Zähneputzens, und diese Abwandlung ist auch so klein, dass sie kaum bewusst wahrgenommen wird, aber sie ist da, und sie ist der Grund, warum diese Formulierung seltener verwendet wird als die erste.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort! Sie haben meine Wahrnehmung bestätigt, dass gebundene Objekte und Bestimmungen als trennbare Präfixe behandeln werden sollen.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Mich hatte u.a. stutzig gemacht, dass das _sich_ als Teil dieser "semantischen Einheit" nicht in die Verneinung einbezogen wird. Geht nicht, wegen Wackernagel (s.u.). Was die Interpretation der Stellungsvarianten angeht: Die verstehe ich als nachgetragene und gewissermaßen künstliche, jedenfalls pädagogisierende Erklärungsversuche. Meine Vermutung ist, dass die Umgangssprache sich mit ihren vielen zusätzlichen Betonungsmöglichkeiten hier einige semantisch kaum abgrenzbare Freiheiten herausnehmen kann. Aber: Diese sind, in Abstufungen, umgangssprachlich...

Comment: [umgangssprachlich ...] ..., will sagen: sprechsprachlich. Wenn man den Satz "_Mein Kind will sich heute die Zähne nicht **putzen**_" auf putzen betont, hört er sich tatsächlich seltsam an, aber "_Mein Kind will sich heute die **Zähne** nicht putzen_" mit einem nur beiläufig betonten _Zähne_ wäre in meiner Region absolut normal, nur würde man das nicht schreiben, weil Betonungen nicht verschriftlicht werden. Meine Vermutung dazu: Die Fokussierungsmöglichkeiten durch Betonung greifen stark in die schrift- bzw. standardsprachlichen Stellungsregeln ein.

Answer (score 4):

> Mein Kind will sich heute die Zähne nicht putzen. Mein Kind will sich heute keine Zähne putzen.

Das sind beides richtige Sätze. Wenn ich einen auswählen müsste, würde ich sagen der erste Satz klingt mehr nach Hochdeutsch.

Man könnte auch den ersten Satz noch etwas umstellen "Mein Kind will sich heute nicht die Zähne putzen." Dann wäre man näher an deiner Lösung, das nicht vor den Ausdruck zu stellen.

Comment: Ah so! Da kann ich gebundene Akkusativobjekte auch mit "nicht" verneinen, genau wie in meinem Beispiel mit "in die Schule"?

Comment: @ALÖ Nein, es wird trotzdem das Verb verneint, auch wenn "nicht" weiter vorne steht.

Comment: Ja, genau das meinte ich. Also um die ganze Konstruktion (Verb + gebundenes Akkusativobjekt) zu verneinen, kann man "nicht" benutzen und es vor diese Konstruktion stellen, richtig?

- Ich werde nicht in den Urlaub fahren. ("nicht" verneint das Prädikat mit gebundenem Adverbialbestimmung)
- Ich werde mir nicht die Zähne putzen. ("nicht" verneint das Prädikat mit gebundenem Akkusativobjekt).

Answer (score 4):

Die Konstruktion aus Dativ + bestimmter Artikel + Körperteil bezeichnet einen unveräusserlichen Besitz, vgl. dazu den Wikipedia-Artikel [Alienabilität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienabilit%C3%A4t). Wenn als Dativ ein Reflexivpronomen steht, so wird impliziert, dass es sich um einen eigenen Körperteil der betreffenden Person handelt:

1. Das Kind putzt sich die Zähne.

Ohne das Reflexivpronomen versteht man, dass es nicht um die eigenen Zähne des Kinds geht. Ein Satz wie der folgende wäre etwa denkbar, wenn vom Lieblingsplüschtier des Kinds die Rede ist:

2. Das Kind putzt ihm die Zähne.

Die Rede ohne einen Dativ impliziert hingegen, dass es nicht um die unveräusserlichen Zähne eines bestimmten Wesens geht, sondern um veräusserliche Zähne. Also wäre ein Satz wie der folgende etwa dann denkbar, wenn es um einen Raum geht, wo viele Spielzeugzähne herumliegen, oder wenn es um die ganze Plüschtiersammlung des Kinds geht:

3. Das Kind putzt Zähne.

Die alltägliche Hygieneverrichtung des Zähne-Putzens nennt die Zähne stets im Plural. Wenn hingen von einem einzigen Zahn die Rede ist, so denkt man eher an einen lose herumliegenden:

4. Das Kind putzt einen Zahn.

Im Unterschied dazu erscheint die Kombination aus reflexivem Dativ + unbestimmtem Artikel ungewöhnlich. Dies dürfte wohl daran liegen, dass die Unveräusserlichkeit der eigenen Zähne mit der Unbestimmtheit im Widerspruch steht:

5. Das Kind putzt sich einen Zahn.

Erst in der Verstärkung mit «einzig» wird der Satz etwas plausibler:

6. Das Kind putzt sich einen einzigen Zahn.

Geradezu ungrammatisch erscheint die Kombination aus Reflexivpronomen + unbestimmtem artikellosen Substantiv im Plural:

7. Das Kind putzt sich Zähne.

Die Unwahrscheinlichkeit dieses Satzes liegt wohl daran, dass eigene unveräusserliche Körperteile sachlogisch gesehen immer bestimmt sind.

### Negation

Die Negation von Satz 1) erfolgt mit dem Wort «nicht»:

8. Das Kind putzt sich die Zähne nicht.

Im Kontrast zu anderen Körperteilen erfolgt die Negation ebenfalls mit «nicht»:

9. Das Kind putzt sich nicht die Zähne, sondern nur die Fingernägel.

Im Gegensatz dazu erscheint die Negation mit «keine» wenig plausibel, da sie – wie oben in Satz 7) – unbestimmte eigene Körperteile voraussetzt:

10. Das Kind putzt sich keine Zähne, sondern nur Fingernägel.

Denkbar wäre eine Negation mit «kein» bei der Verstärkung mit «einzig» wie oben in Satz 6):

11. Das Kind putzt sich keinen einzigen Zahn, sondern nur einen Fingernagel.

Plausibel ist eine Negation mit «keine» ebenfalls dann, wenn es um unbestimmte Zähne geht, beispielsweise um lose auf dem Boden herumliegende – also als Negation eines Satzes wie 3):

12. Das Kind putzt keine Zähne, sondern Legosteine.

Eine Negation mit «kein» setzt also ganz bestimmte Kontexte wie in 11) oder 12) voraus.

Comment: Oh, vielen Dank für so eine ausführliche Erklärung. Meine nächste Frage wäre dann, ob im Fall, wenn das Verb am Ende des Satzes steht, soll "nicht" vor "die Zähne" oder vor "putzen" stehen?

Beispiel:
Mein Kind will sich die Zähne nicht putzen.
oder
Mein Kind will sich nicht die Zähne putzen.

Ich glaube, der erste Satz ist richtig, oder?

Comment: @ALÖ: Das wäre eine gleichartige Differenzierung wie zwischen Satz 8) und Satz 9): Für eine unmarkierte Negierung des ganzes Satzes steht das _nicht_ am Ende («das Kind will sich die Zähne nicht putzen»), und für eine kontrastive Negierung von _die Zähne_ steht das _nicht_ davor («das Kind will sich nicht die Zähne putzen, sondern nur die Fingernägel»).

Comment: @mach - Sehe ich tendenziell anders herum. Unmarkiert ist für mich _... will sich nicht die Zähne putzen_, mit _sich die Zähne putzen_ als einem kulturell etablierten Programmpunkt der Morgenroutine, verkürzt z.B. in: _Zähne putzen / Zähneputzen nicht vergessen!_ Man kann jedoch mit der Betonung spielen: _... hat sich heute die **Zähne** nicht geputzt /... hat sich heute **nicht** [Hauptton] die **Zähne** [Nebenton] geputzt / ... hat sich heute nicht **die Zähne** geputzt_ -  schwierig! Möglicherweise kann man _die Zähne_ wahlweise ins Prädikat integrieren oder nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Sehe ich praktisch genau so wie Clemens. Der Standard-Infinitiv dazu wäre *sich die Zähne putzen*. Es könnte ja auch heißen *sich seine Zähne putzen, seine Zähne putzen, die Zähne putzen, Zähne putzen* und das alles auch mit *bürsten, reinigen, schrubben* usw., aber all diese Varianten weichen von der Standard-Struktur ab, welche wir bei *sich die Haare kämmen, sich die Hände waschen* usw. in ähnlicher Weise haben, plus der lexikalisierten, ziemlich stabilen Kollokation *Zähne + putzen*. Das wäre dann insofern ein gebundenes Akkusativobjekt, und in der Tat verhält sich das Ganze syntaktisch wie ein großes Verb mit trennbarem Präfix.

Was die Stellung von *sich* (Dativ) angeht, muss es nach [Wackernagels "Gesetz"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wackernagels_Gesetz) auf der ["Wackernagelposition"](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/714) = am linken Rand des Mittelfeldes stehen, welcher durch *will* markiert wird. Solche kurzen und unbetonten Pronomen schließen sich dann dieser linken Satzklammer unmittelbar an, *will sich* ist damit eine untrennbare Folge - es sei denn, man heiße Adorno und wolle stilistisch sich über die Menge erheben ; ).

Der genannte Standard-Infinitiv enthält den Artikel *die*, eine Verneinung mit *nicht* liegt daher näher als eine Verneinung mit *kein/e*, welche vor allem bei indefinitem und Null-Artikel üblich ist. Umgangssprachlich nimmt man das jedoch nicht so genau, und auch die *keine-*Verneinung dürfte vorkommen. *Keine* ist hier eine Artikelform (Negativ-Artikel) und kann von dem Bezugsnomen (hier) nicht getrennt werden, dadurch erklärt sich die Stellung direkt beim Nomen. Umgangssprachlich kommen jedoch Sätze vor wie "*Kaffee haben wir leider keinen mehr*", analog zu "*(An) Kuchen ist noch viel / etwas / ein bisschen da*" oder "*Saft haben wir noch welchen im Kühlschrank.*"

Es verhält sich meiner Beobachtung nach tatsächlich so, dass gebundene Objekte (und andere gebundene Prädikatsbestandteile) ins Prädikat integriert sind, somit bezieht sich die Verneinung auf das gesamte Prädikat und tritt hier vor das gebundene Objekt. Die andere aufgefundene Stellungsvariante könnte eine Kontrastivtonung sein (*... will sich die Zähne nicht putzen, nur spülen* / *... will sich die Zähne nicht putzen, nur das Gesicht waschen und die Haare kämmen*) oder eine Fokussierung auf eben ***die Zähne***, wodurch sie aus dem Prädikat herausfallen und damit in Grenzen stellungsvariabel werden (z.B. auch: *will sich die Zähne heute nicht putzen* statt *sich heute die Zähne nicht ...*).

Comment: Danke schön! So dachte ich auch...

Bei dieser Logik ist auch die Konstruktion "in (den) Urlaub fahren" untrennbar und wird als gesamter Prädikat verneint?

"Ich werde morgen nicht in den Urlaub fahren" statt "Ich werde morgen in den Urlaub nicht fahren"?

Comment: Ja, sehe ich so. Interessant, dass hier der Artikel eingeklammert ist. Diese Art von Artikelschwund ist häufiger zu beobachten; "_ ... hat morgen Prüfung; ... macht jetzt Führerschein_", ich bin mir unsicher, wie es da mit der Verneinung aussieht (_hat morgen nicht Prüfung / hat morgen keine Prüfung_ - ?), aber da wäre die Frage, ob dafür überhaupt ein kommunikativer Bedarf besteht. Außerdem sind wir hier schon deutlich im Umgangssprachlichen, und sowieso: Ich selbst lebe im Ruhrgebiet, wie sich die anderen Regionen da ausdrücken, weiß ich nicht.